# Watir open multiple browser's or tab's

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

How can I open more than one browser using my code-watir, for example via a `while` loop from 0 to 10?

Here is my code:

```
require 'watir-webdriver'
require 'headless'
class Page
    @headless = Headless.new
    @headless.start
    @browser = Watir::Browser.start 'bit.ly/***'
    def self.get_connection

        puts "Browser started"  
        puts @browser.title
        @browser.driver.manage.timeouts.implicit_wait = 3 #3 seconds

        @browser.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$tresc$111').select_value('6')
        puts "Selected country"  
        @browser.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$tresc$222').wait_until_present
        @browser.select_list(:name => 'ctl00$tresc$333').select_value('95')
        puts "Selected city" 
    end

    def self.close_connection
        @browser.close
        @headless.destroy
    end
end

Page.get_connection
Page.close_connection
```

But how to do something like this?

```
while i < 10
Page.get_connection
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should open ten browsers:

```
10.times {Watir::Browser.new}
```

If you want to use the browsers later, you can put them in a hash:

```
browsers = {}
(0..9).each {|i| browsers[i] = Watir::Browser.new}
browsers[0].goto "google.com"
browsers[1].goto "yahoo.com"
```

Comment: but also how to do it via class variables @ ?

Comment: Just replace `browsers[i]` with `@browsers[i]`. You should read a book on Ruby. Writing Ruby code is way easier when you know the basics of the language.

Comment: i just didn't know that class variable could ve written as array

Comment: It is actually a hash. Reading a book on Ruby would really help. :)

Comment: also, if it could help, not for 5, but more than average, and from first probe, i done ruby test on odesk...

Comment: I did not want to say you were stupid. I apologize if it sounded like that. I have noticed that you do not know some basic stuff, so I suggested a book. That is all. I do not know a lot of stuff too.